# Markup and styling for overlaying images and css blur

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a blurred section that is 100% screen hight and 25% width.

**Example**

[image]

This is the code I have for it thus far.

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url('autumn.jpg') no-repeat center 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar1 {
    max-width: 25%;
    background-image: url('autumn.jpg') no-repeat center 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <main>
        <aside id="sidebar1">
            ...
        </aside>
```

Now, I've tried utilizing this JavaScript library: [Blur.js](http://www.blurjs.com/)

This isn't the best solution as it is unstable and causes Chrome to crash often. I know that with CSS3 I can use the `filter: blur()` property. However, I can't seem to get the markup/styling properties I need to accomplish this. Basically I need that sidebar to be able to dynamically render the blur when the screen size changes. Is the filter property only applicable on an `<img>` element? I can't seem to get it to apply to he body via using the `background-image` property.

Answer (score 0):

[This thing I've made](http://liamness.co.uk/fractal-viewer/) has an example of a blur effect using CSS. It should work on any DOM element, not just images. My guess is that you need a -webkit-filter: blur() (if you're testing this with Chrome, Safari or Opera) as well as filter: blur(). I think it's best you avoid a js library, I can't imagine image processing in javascript is particularly performant.